# How do you add an object to the dictionary in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm currently trying to create an AddBooking method which adds a given Booking object to the booking dictionary (using the bookingID of the Booking as the key) but I'm really unsure how to do it, I have started it but I'm not sure what to firstly put in the bracket and then what goes in the method. Any help or advise would be appreciated :)

```
namespace TheatreShows
{
    public class Show
    {
        private string title;
        private Dictionary<int, Booking> bookings;

        public string Title
        {
            get { return title; }
            set { title = value; }
        }

        public Show(string title)
        {
            this.title = title;
            this.bookings = new Dictionary<int, Booking>();
        }

        public void AddBooking (int bookingID, Booking ..?)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For any standard language operation refer to language documentation rather than to SO: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: In the future you should at least try to look at the doc page before asking such a basic question. It is literally the first method on the methods list [in the dictionary documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There two ways

```
if (!this.bookings.ContainsKey(bookingId))
    this.bookings.Add(bookingID, booking);
```

or

```
this.bookings[bookingID] = booking;
```

In second case there is no risk of adding the same key twice. But if there is an entry with provided key the value will be replaced by the new one.

Comment: Good thing using `ContainsKey` check before adding.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do a TryAdd in that instance? That way the key is only looked up once.

Comment: There is `TryGetValue` but I haven't seen any `TryAdd` supported by a standard c# dictionary.

Comment: @AllanElder, `TryAdd` is provided with `ConcurrentDictionary`, There is no `TryAdd` with `Dictionary<T,T>`

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something as this seems too easy:

```
public void AddBooking (int bookingID, Booking booking)
{
    this.bookings.Add(bookingId, booking);
}
```

If the values may already exist, you will want to test if that key exists in the dictionary first and decide to replace it, or ignore the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.bookings.Add(bookingID, booking);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of using Add as you can have an exception if the key exists; if duplicate keys are a possibility, you should check for existence first. But to just add or update, use the indexer.

```
public void AddBooking (int bookingID, Booking booking)
{
    bookings[bookingID] = booking;
}
```